# Windows Phone 8 Hubtile Source and Background Image Loading

Tags: windows-phone-8

Currently we are using the HubTile to display a large (50-70) images and text overlayed.

```
<toolkit:HubTile Margin="0,12,12,0"  
     Title="{Binding title}"
     Message="{Binding itemLink}"
     Source="{Binding media}"
     GroupTag="BindingHubTile"
     Style="{StaticResource HubTileStyle1}">
</toolkit:HubTile>
<TextBlock Height="Auto" FontSize="14" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding votes}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,15,-7" />
```

The source is bound to a URI that is retrieved from a webserver which then allows the phone to download the image and display it. The problem is, with this amount of images we are finding that the UI is locking up.

Our hubtiles are loaded into a listbox by means of listbox.ItemSource.

Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set to an image - URI it downloads in background and doesn't lock the UI - tested.

The only thing that remains is to find where you have locked it.

I had a similar project, but i created CustomControls to fill ListBox. Custom Control contained - date field, text and image.

Image was loaded like this:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(article.ImageURL));
NLBI.Thumbnail.Source = image;
```

And all images were loading async in background and UI was usable.

Comment: Thanks for the input - we'll give it a go.